# nginx ingress controller root path(/) mapping to /path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an nodejs application running on kubernetes and the url is `https://example.com`. The same application also serves '/api'. My requirement is when I hit `https://example.com`, in the background it should hit `https://example.com/api` but in frontend, it should show `https://example.com` only.

I have already tried with below configuration of nginx ingress using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api` but it doesnt work.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: in other words, it shall connect you to the backend that serves `example.com/api` , but merely display `example.com` in browser's URL. Am I right?

Comment: @ajay.kumar.awscloud any luck here?